# How to trigger an observer ONCE after a for-in loop?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `for-in` loop that's running async functions. When all of those async functions are complete, I'd like to call the observer to then reload my `UITableView`. Essentially, here's what I have:

```
   var reloadTable:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if reloadTable {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) { // 1
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // 2
                        self.tableView.reloadData() // 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func arrayContains(array:[[String:AnyObject]]) {

        for song in array {

            // async function with completion block({

              self.reloadTable = true

           })
        }

     reloadTable = false

    }
```

The problem is that the `tableView` is reloading after every iteration over the for loop. I'd expect it to only be called after all songs have been iterated over in the array. Reason being, I'm asynchronously getting album art for songs in a `UITableView`, but they're downloading out of order. So I need to append them to an array at a particular index, *and then* reload the table view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GCD's dispatch group](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19) can be used for this purpose.

```
    func arrayContains(array:[[String:AnyObject]]) {

        var downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()

        for song in array {
            dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
          //  async function with completion block({
                dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

            })
        }

        dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.reloadTable = true   //Take care of cyclic reference here.
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better to use `dispatch_group_notify`.

Comment: Dispatch_group_notify takes different arguments.

Comment: On `dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)` I'm getting `Missing argument for parameter #3 in call and on `dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue)` I'm getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'GlobalMainQueue'`

Comment: @dperk: I have edited the answer. This should work now. I have also given link to the documentation which you can refer in case you have any ambiguity.

Comment: And I've edited it to remove a leftover line from the prior version.

Comment: Shouldn't the `self.reloadTable` within the dispatch_group_notify be set to false? And set `self.reloadTable = true` be called within the completion block?

Comment: Can I get confirmation on this @robmayoff & @tek3?

Comment: You should get rid of the `reloadTable` property entirely, and just call `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside the `dispatch_group_notify` block.

Answer (score 0):

How about add a count do indicate loading/loaded:

```
var loadingCount = 0
 func arrayContains(array:[[String:AnyObject]]) {

        for song in array {

            self.loadingCount += 1 // Increase 1 when loading

            // in the completion block({

                self.loadingCount -= 1 // Decrease 1 when loaded

                if(loadingCount == 0){
                   self.reloadTable = true
                }

           })
        }
    }



 // Or you want to be safe, set the total before the loop
    func arrayContains(array:[[String:AnyObject]]) {

                self.loadingCount = count(array)
                for song in array {
                    // in the completion block({

                        self.loadingCount -= 1 // Decrease 1 when loaded

                        if(loadingCount == 0){
                           self.reloadTable = true
                        }

                   })
                }
            }
```

Comment: That does the same thing because the loadingCount is going to = 0 after every completion block has finished.

Comment: Are you sure? unless your Async logic is faster than light speed, execute time of one line code.  Try it first.  Or you want to be safe, you can set it to the total before the loop.

Comment: That does nothing. It's resetting to zero after every block, so `self.reloadTable = true` will be called after every `song` in `array`. I only want `reloadTable = false` to be called once.

Comment: Come on, have you try? Could you show me the complete code, especially the async function, I want to see how to did it.

Comment: I edited the answer, you can set to total before the loop, as I said earlier.